# Display 'Present' if Row exists, display 'Missing' if'otherwise

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, case-when

The code below checks if a row is returned. If true, it should display 'PRESENT' ELSE 'MISSING'.

I have tried values that will return either 0 or 1 but both returns 'MISSING'. What could I have missed here.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UserCheck (
    IN p_ACCEPTED_BY VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
    DECLARE isPresent INT(10);

SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ETOOLS.UserTermsAndConditions
    WHERE ACCEPTED_BY = 'p_ACCEPTED_BY') INTO isPresent;

    IF isPresent = 1 THEN
        SELECT 'PRESENT';
    ELSE
        SELECT 'MISSING';
    END IF;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ' ' on parameter. should be:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ETOOLS.UserTermsAndConditions
    WHERE ACCEPTED_BY = p_ACCEPTED_BY) INTO isPresent;
```